# Wordpress - Better way of prepending product category to the title (Woocommerce / Astra)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to prepend a Woocommerce single product page title (in the header) with the category so it looks like

*Category*

**Product Title**

This is what I have so far:

```
function prepend_category_to_title($title, $id) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat = $term->name;
        break;
    }
    if( is_product() ) {
        $title = $product_cat . $title;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'prepend_category_to_title', 10, 2);
```

I can get it to prepend the title fine but using `the_title` outputs the category name to every single menu item and every single breadcrumb as well.

I see from this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309151/apply-the-title-filter-in-post-page-title-but-not-in-menu-title that this is expected behaviour and I can add further filters to remove these extra outputs. e.g. `add_filter( 'pre_wp_nav_menu'...`

But this seems horribly inefficient and messy. Additionally, prepending the title this way means that the category text also gets wrapped in the title `<h1>` tags which I don't want as the category name needs to be above the product title in smaller `<h5>` tags (and different font).

To make this slightly more complex, due to the theme I am using (Astra), the product title sits in a header outside of Woocommerce's 
`woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook.

How can I prepend the product title with the product category in a more elegant way? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is based on hook so it will not create an issue. But if you need to proceed based on WooCommerce way then you need to skip WordPress hook `the_title` and need to use WooCommerce hook.

`woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook is associate with title, price, expert, .. on single product page. see below code of line that shows hook and there related function.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );
```

To go with Woocommerce, you need to remove the actual hook and reinitate the function like below. Hope below code justify your question.You can put this snippet in your theme's `functions.php` file

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_title',5);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_my_single_title',5);

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_my_single_title' ) ) {
   function woocommerce_my_single_title() {
?>
            /*
             your logic goes here
             No need to return data, just echo/print
            */
<?php
   }

}
```